# IOS: save subview with his touch and tap abilities

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, save, subviews

I am trying to make a free drawing app, that when the user is drawing a circle on screen i alloc/init a  UIview circle class and add it as a sub view.
then i can move this circle that was created around the screen and tap it to change the color inside of it.
i want to be able to save the drawing and other drawing each on different file and to be able to load them and to continue drawing and to use the abilities to move and tap the subview after i load it.
what is the best way to save and how do i do so?
how can i ensure to continue to use the subviews abilities of touch and tap after i load them?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to save the views properties: colour, x,y position etc to core data or plist .. Then when the user loads that you just re-create the view based on the view's saved properties.